# What are the essential IDA Plugins or IDA Python scripts that you use?

Tags: tools, ida, idapython

I'm a bit of a novice with IDA Pro, and have been discovering some of the excellent plugins available from the RE community as well as its vendors. My small list of plugins that I have found extremely valuable to me are:

- [Hex-Rays Decompiler](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml) (commercial) - convert program to pseudo-C
- [IDA Toolbag](http://thunkers.net/~deft/code/toolbag/) - Adds too much awesome functionality to IDA to list. [Just see/read about it](http://thunkers.net/~deft/code/toolbag/docs.html#Usage).
- [IDAscope](https://bitbucket.org/daniel_plohmann/simplifire.idascope/) - Function tagging/inspection, WinAPI lookup, Crypto identification

Granted, this is a very short list. What IDA Pro scripts/plugins do you find essential?

Comment: This question is pretty subjective and more like a poll. However, there probably are many plugins and scripts that would be helpful to many so this could be a community wiki.

Comment: I intended to make this a community wiki, but it does not appear to be an option.

Comment: @HenryHeikkinen Using community wiki to shoehorn polls into a questions and answers platform turned out to be a mistake, it is no longer done. See [The future of community wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/). Polls are not accepted on Stack Exchange, and I voted to close accordingly.

Comment: @KenB There aren't any restrictions for the private beta. [CW polls were a youthful mistake on SO, now fixed.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)

Comment: Perhaps such a subjective list could be added to the tag wiki of [idapro].

Comment: If we take StackExchange lore out of the equation, it seems very difficult to argue that such a question is in fact "not constructive".  So at best we should say "closed as not conforming to the whims of the StackExchange metamoderation community.""

Comment: This is not a constructive question in its current form and I dont think it should be reopened. If users do feel this is an important discussion, then I suggest dealing with this as discussed here  http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-should-book-tutorial-questions-be-dealt-with . The discussion should be moved to meta and the best/essential plugins can be added to the Tag Wiki based on agreement/votes.

Comment: It's worth visiting plugin contest HP. https://www.hex-rays.com/contests/2018/index.shtml

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are binary diffing plugins also that are very handy to analyse vulnerabilities: [patchdiff2](https://code.google.com/p/patchdiff2) and [zynamics bindiff](http://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html). They can help you analyse the patches that the binary had and very usefull to analyse i.e. why the application was vulnerable before the patch and how the vendor fixed it.

Besides these two plugins for IDA there's [DarunGrim](http://www.darungrim.org/), another excellent binary diffing tool.

Comment: Have you tried [this one](http://course.cs.tau.ac.il/secws12/?q=projects/reverse-engineering-integrated-database)? I'd be interested in your opinion.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky it sounds really interesting. I'll take a deep look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Here's a few I use regularly:

- Microsoft [VC++ RTTI and EH parser scripts](http://www.hexblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/recon-2012-skochinsky-scripts.zip). There is [a reimplementation](http://www.macromonkey.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=705) as a plugin (but I haven't tried it).
- `memcpy.idc` from IDA's idc directory. Very simple but useful when dealing with firmwares that copy code around.
- `renimp.idc` when doing PE unpacking. Though recently it's been supplanted by UUNP's [manual reconstruct](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=403) feature.
- a tiny script to save selected bytes to a file. Useful for extracting embedded binaries from droppers.

---

```
#include <idc.idc>
static main()
{
  auto s,e,f,name;
  s = SelStart();
  e = SelEnd();
  if (s==BADADDR || e==BADADDR)
    return;
  name = form("dump_%08X.bin", s);
  f = fopen(name,"wb");
  Message("Saving %a-%a to %s...", s, e, name);
  savefile(f,0,s,e-s);
  Message("done.\n");
  fclose(f);
}
```

---

Also, I often write small IDC or Python snippets that do something specific to the binary I'm reversing, e.g. parsing a custom symbol table, or converting some specific byte sequence to code. These are usually not reused much.

Answer (score 7):

For analysing RPC I use [mIDA](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/186/mIDA):
mIDA is a plugin for the IDA disassembler that can extract RPC interfaces from a binary file and recreate the associated IDL definition. mIDA is free and fully integrates with the latest version of IDA (5.2 or later).
This plugin can be used to :

```
* Navigate to RPC functions in IDA
* Analyze RPC function arguments
* Understand RPC structures
* Reconstruct an IDL definition file
```

The IDL code generated by mIDA can be, most of the time, recompiled with the MIDL compiler from Microsoft (midl.exe).

mIDA is freely distributed to the community by Tenable in the hope it will be useful to you and help research engineers to work more effectively on RPC programs. However, Tenable does not provide support for this tool and offers no guarantee regarding its use or output. Please read the end-user license agreement before using this program.

[image: Sample output of mIDA]

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add [collabREate](http://www.idabook.com/collabreate) - plugin, which allow to do reverse engineering in the small team, all share the same IDA session.