# Could you list some useful plugins and scripts for IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

I am just starting to use [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/). After discussing a bit with the community, it seems that IDA Pro plugins and scripts are quite important to reach a good level of productivity while analyzing a program.

What are some *must have* plugins for IDApro that you would recommend for an everyday usage.

Comment: what kind of program? what kind of analysis? that's an extremely broad question so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the essential IDA Plugins or IDA Python scripts that you use?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59/what-are-the-essential-ida-plugins-or-ida-python-scripts-that-you-use)

Comment: IMHO, most useful plugin - one You familiar with and one that automate and help in YOUR work with IDA. When You'll learn IDA a bit more, You'll find out Your methods, and then - choose Your plugins to automate process.

Comment: I converted it into a community wiki so that anyone can edit it and add a list of plugins as I think the question is very common.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the two main tasks for which I intend to use IDApro.

Comment: @Remko: You're right. This seems to be duplicate. Should I delete this question ?

Comment: @perror That one was closed. I think having one is good idea as long as it's a wiki.

Comment: @perror Let's go with Peter's suggestion for wiki...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## By Architecture

*Generic helpers for reverse engineering of a specific architecture.*

### ia32

### amd64

### ARM

---

## By Operating System

*Generic helpers for reverse engineering of a specific operating system.*

### Windows

### Linux

---

## By Compiler

*Generic helpers for reverse engineering of binaries generated using a specific compiler.*

### Microsoft Visual Studio

#### [Microsoft Visual C++ Reversing Helpers](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/196/Microsoft_VC++_Reversing_Helpers)

> These IDC scripts help with the reversing of MSVC programs. One script scans the whole program for typical SEH/EH code sequences and comments all related structures and fields. The other script scans the whole program for RTTI structures and vftables.

### GCC

### Delphi

#### [Delphi RTTI script](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/61/Delphi_RTTI_script)

> This script deals with Delphi RTTI structures

### Borland

#### [Borland C++ Builder RTTI](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/72/Borland_C++_Builder_RTTI_Support)

> Borland C++ Builder Run Time Type Information (RTTI) support for IDA Pro

---

## By Technology

*Generic helpers for reverse engineering of a technology.*

### COM

#### [COM Plugin](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/10/Com_Plugin_v1.2)

> The plugin tries to extract the symbol information from
> the typelibrary of the COM component. It will then set the
> function names of interface methods and their parameters, and
> finally add a comment with the MIDL-style declaration of the
> interface method.

### Remote Procedure Call

#### [mIDA](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/186/mIDA)

> mIDA is a plugin for the IDA disassembler that can extract RPC interfaces from a binary file and recreate the associated IDL definition. mIDA is free and fully integrates with the latest version of IDA (5.2 or later)

---

## Cryptography

*Generic helpers for reverse engineering of encryption and decryption algorithms.*

### Signature Based

#### [FindCrypt2](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/189/FindCrypt2)

> The idea behind it pretty simple: since almost all crypto algorithms use magic constants, we will just look for these constants in the program body.
> The plugin supports virtually all crypto algorithms and hash functions.

---

## Deobfuscation

*Plugins and scripts for removing obfuscations from disassembly.*

### ia32

#### [Optimice](http://code.google.com/p/optimice/)

> Optimice applies common optimization techniques on obfuscated code to make it more readable/user friendly. This plugin enables you to remove some common obfuscations and rewrite code to a new segment.

Comment: I started with this small template. I have more that I want to add but I don't have time right now. Anyone else, edit away.

Comment: is there a reliable mirror for the mida plugin? It'd be nice if we could ensure all download links work.

Comment: @broadway: send it to IDAPalace?!