# where can I get mIDA

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

[Some posts](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59/what-are-the-essential-ida-plugins-or-ida-python-scripts-that-you-use/62#62) reference the [mIDA](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/186/mIDA) plugin, but the download site seems unavailable. Is there any mirror or a link to an archive version?

Comment: try to ask directly to author, you've his email

Comment: I couldn't find mIDA online, so I e-mailed the author.

Comment: @Ange: how about setting up a mirror on Bitbucket or Github, the license allowing, and then answer with that? Edit: oh or on Google Code ... your site is there of course.

Comment: yeah, that would be good, but I don't see myself maintaining a file archive on top of the rest: why Woodman or Openrce didn't host a local copy is beyond me. It would be trivial to also put it on a google code project, but I'm not sure that's compatible with the licences.

Comment: I don't think the source has been released so this discussion is moot so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was just sent [mIDA-1.0.10](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yj30fqj2dxxlmnj/mIDA-1.0.10.zip), from 2008.

```
mIDA is an IDA plugin which extracts RPC interfaces and recreates the associated IDL file.
mIDA supports inline, interpreted and fully interpreted server stubs.
```

Comment: I didn't get it from the author (no answer yet), so there might be a newer version.

Comment: mIDA_v1.0.10.zip can also be found at Aaron Portnoy's site  [here](http://thunkers.net/~deft/code/tools/) as well, for another source, but I'm likewise unsure if that is the latest version.

Comment: The link is not accessible..can you please update the link if possible..please?

Comment: https://github.com/sourceincite/tools/tree/master/pymsrpc/mIDA & https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3469